# React 'useContext' hook not re-rendering after context updates with database data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-context

I am using React's Context API to share data that most of my components need.

The Context is initially defined, but shortly receives data from the Firebase database (please see `IdeaContext.tsx`). I define the context in a functional component and the display component, which returns a small card based on the information received.

However, the component doesn't render when I start the development server with Yarn. Instead, in order to get it to render, I have to write `console.log('something')` inside the display component and then it suddenly re-renders. However, when I refresh the server, it again doesn't render.

How can I make my component render immediately (or at least after the context updates with the data from the database?)

---

Code:

Context Definition:

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IdeaContextType, Idea } from "../t";
import {ideasRef} from './firebase'

function getIdeas() {
  var arr: Array<Idea> = [];

  ideasRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let items = snapshot.val()

      snapshot.forEach( (idea) => {
        const obj = idea.val()
        arr.push({
          title: obj.title,
          description: obj.description,
          keyID: obj.keyID
        })
        console.log(arr)
      })
  })
  return arr
}

const IdeaContextDefaultValues: IdeaContextType = {
  ideas: [],
  setIdeas: () => {},
};

const IdeaContext = createContext<IdeaContextType>(IdeaContextDefaultValues)

const IdeaContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [ideas, setIdeas] = useState<Array<Idea>>(
    IdeaContextDefaultValues.ideas);
  
  useEffect( ()=> {
      console.log('getting info')
      setIdeas(getIdeas())
  }, [])


  useEffect( () => {
    console.log('idea change: ', ideas)
  }, [ideas])

  return (
    <IdeaContext.Provider value={{ ideas, setIdeas }}>
      {children}
    </IdeaContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Displayer and Card Component

```
import React, { FC, ReactElement, useContext } from "react";
import IdeaCreator from "./IdeaCreator";
import { IdeaContext } from "./IdeaContext";
import { Idea } from "../t";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const IdeaPost:React.FC<Idea> = ({title, keyID, description}):ReactElement => {

  console.log('Received',title,description,keyID)
  return (
    <div className="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
      <img
        className="w-full"
        src="#"
        alt="Oopsy daisy"
      />
      <div className="px-6 py-4">
        <div className="font-bold text-xl mb-2"> <Link to={"ideas/" + keyID} key= {keyID}> {title}</Link>  </div>
        <p className="text-gray-700 text-base">{description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const IdeaDisplay:FC<any> = (props:any):ReactElement => {


  const { ideas, setIdeas } = useContext(IdeaContext)
  console.log('Ideas in display: ', ideas)
  console.log('test') //This is what I comment and uncommend to get it to show

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap ">
      {ideas.map((idea) => {
        console.log(idea)
        console.log('Sending',idea.title,idea.description,idea.keyID)
        console.log(typeof idea.keyID)
        return ( 
          <IdeaPost
            title={idea.title}
            description={idea.description}
            keyID = {idea.keyID}
            key = {idea.keyID * 100}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default IdeaDisplay;
```

---

Solution Code:

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IdeaContextType, Idea } from "../t";
import {ideasRef} from './firebase'

async function getIdeas() {
  var arr: Array<Idea> = [];

  const snapshot = await ideasRef.once("value");

  snapshot.forEach((idea) => {
    const obj = idea.val();
    arr.push({
      title: obj.title,
      description: obj.description,
      keyID: obj.keyID,
    });
    console.log(arr);
  });

  return arr
}

const IdeaContextDefaultValues: IdeaContextType = {
  ideas: [],
  setIdeas: () => {},
};

const IdeaContext = createContext<IdeaContextType>(IdeaContextDefaultValues)

const IdeaContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [ideas, setIdeas] = useState<Array<Idea>>(
    IdeaContextDefaultValues.ideas);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("getting info");
      const setup = async () => {
        const ideas = await getIdeas();
        setIdeas(ideas);


      };

      setup()


    }, []);
  


  useEffect( () => {
    console.log('idea change: ', ideas)

    const updateDatabase = async () => {
        await ideasRef.update(ideas)
        console.log('updated database')
    }

    updateDatabase()

  }, [ideas])

  return (
    <IdeaContext.Provider value={{ ideas, setIdeas }}>
      {children}
    </IdeaContext.Provider>
  );
};

export {IdeaContext, IdeaContextProvider}
```

Comment: `setIdeas(getIdeas())` - `getIdeas()` fetches data asynchronously, so calling it like you are will just return an empty array. One way to solve the problem is to pass the `setIdeas` function to the `getIdeas` function and when the data is received, call `setIdeas` function, passing in the data from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you would need to use `once` and not `on` if you want to get the data only once. If you want to use a realtime listener you could send the `setIdeas` to your function. Also try to be carefull with `async/away` calls to the Firebase sdk. Your code could look like this:

```js
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IdeaContextType, Idea } from "../t";
import { ideasRef } from "./firebase";

async function getIdeas() {
  var arr: Array<Idea> = [];

  const snapshot = await ideasRef.once("value");

  let items = snapshot.val();

  snapshot.forEach((idea) => {
    const obj = idea.val();
    arr.push({
      title: obj.title,
      description: obj.description,
      keyID: obj.keyID,
    });
    console.log(arr);
  });

  return arr;
}

const IdeaContextDefaultValues: IdeaContextType = {
  ideas: [],
  setIdeas: () => {},
};

const IdeaContext = createContext < IdeaContextType > IdeaContextDefaultValues;

const IdeaContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [ideas, setIdeas] =
    useState < Array < Idea >> IdeaContextDefaultValues.ideas;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("getting info");
    const getData = async () => {
      const ideas = await getIdeas();
      setIdeas(ideas);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("idea change: ", ideas);
  }, [ideas]);

  return (
    <IdeaContext.Provider value={{ ideas, setIdeas }}>
      {children}
    </IdeaContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Tarik, thank you for the code, I am happy to change my code to be asynchronous. However, I still have the problem. The information is updated to the context, and the console.log statements in the Displayer component confirms that the context is properly received. If the Functional Component is clearly changing, then why isn't it re-rendering and updating when the context updates?

Comment: Never mind, it appears to have fixed the re-render issue. I didn't get why it worked, could you please explain how the two issues were related?

Comment: Sure. Can you show how your current code looks like and what you habe changed.

Comment: I just updated the post with my new Context file.